# Asp.net MVC Html.Renderpartial Problem

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2, html-helper

Well I have this page

< %@ .............. Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage < Something.Models.SomeModel >" %>

< % Html.RenderPartial("SomeControl",Model);% >

and this user control page

< %@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage
< Something.Models.SomeModel>"%>

< p>< %: Html.TextBox("text",Model.Name) %>< /p>

and I get this exception

Cannot covert type 'ASP.views_somecontrol_ascx' to 'System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl'

Any idea about why this is happenig?

Answer (score 1):

Your user control page should inherit from `System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<TModel>` not `System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<TModel>`.

On your user control page use:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<Something.Models.SomeModel>" %>
```

Comment: well it is like that actually I shortened it.

Comment: @hrrrr In your question the control page is inheriting from ViewPage not ViewUserControl